# Extend List of Divs to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to html and I'm trying to float these divs to the right when the `div` get in the `max-height`.

```css
.List {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="List">
  <div> one </div>
  <div> two </div>
  <div> three </div>
  <div> four </div>
  <div> five </div>
</ul>
```

It only shows "one, two, three", I want the other to show up too, but instead extending to the bottom of the page, extend to the right.

Comment: So you want them to be aligned horizontally (like navigation menu) ? By the way why are you set `div` inside `ul` element? This is invalid HTML you should only put `li` element inside `ul`.

Comment: I think the intended behaviour is more that they should flow into columns based on the max-height (i.e. one, two, three in column 1, four and five in column two)?

Comment: Unrelated but, the only direct descendant of a UL is LI.  If you want to have proper syntax change your `<div>`'s to `<li>`'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you set `max-height` with overflow, so that hide the other elements.

And you can't set div directly inside of ul. This is not proper html.

Try to use `ul` and `li` together.

```css
.List {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 50px;
  text-align:right;
}
.List li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="List">
  <li> one </li>
  <li> two </li>
  <li> three </li>
  <li> four </li>
  <li> five </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.list{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
max-height:50px;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.list div{
width:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
</div>
```

You can use flex for this. 
With the property `flex-wrap:wrap;` your list will be adjusted depending of the parent height.

Answer (score 0):

Add display: inline-block; for div.

```css
.List {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 50px;
}
div {
 display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<ul class="List">
  <div> one </div>
  <div> two </div>
  <div> three </div>
  <div> four </div>
  <div> five </div>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is about, once the first column reaches `max-height` remaining things should move to second column, then you can do it with `flex`.

Add `display: flex` and flex-flow: column wrap` will help you to flow your content to next column.

```css
.List {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

```html
<ul class="List">
  <div> one </div>
  <div> two </div>
  <div> three </div>
  <div> four </div>
  <div> five </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Div is not allowed as a direct child of ul

So change the `ul` for a `div` or the `divs` for `li`, and use display block propertie to displays an element as a block element.

```css
.List {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 50px;
}
.List div, .List li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="List">
  <div> one </div>
  <div> two </div>
  <div> three </div>
  <div> four </div>
  <div> five </div>
</div>
<ul class="List">
  <li> one </li>
  <li> two </li>
  <li> three </li>
  <li> four </li>
  <li> five </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have problem with semantics in your HTML code.
HTML spec doesn't allow to put into the `ul`(unsorted list) `div` elements as a child.
You must use `<li>`(list item) tag for this items.

For your task you may use [flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Make element flex by setting to it `display: flex`.
Then use `flex-flow` property to specify that you want child elements goes as a column and wrap if they not fitted to the height of the target block.

To use this decision make sure that all browsers you need support flexbox speсification.
To see this use [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) service.

To make flexbox work at different browser engines equally use autoprefixer for your code: http://autoprefixer.github.io/

Example:

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.list {
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 60px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex; 
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical; 
  -webkit-box-direction: normal; 
      -ms-flex-flow: column wrap; 
          flex-flow: column wrap; 
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div> one </div>
  <div> two </div>
  <div> three </div>
  <div> four </div>
  <div> five </div>
</div>
```

Also, if you want to group items into columns you can use [CSS3 Multicolumn Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts)